# Cuda reusing events to determine execution time of multiple sections

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, gpgpu

I wish to calculate the execution time for two different sections of my cuda code. In order to do so, I am trying to use CudaEvent_t start, stop.
**My question is, can I use the same two events 'start' and 'stop' for calculating execution time in some other section?**

For example:

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);

// SECTION 1
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
cudaMemcpy(..., ..., ..., cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);

cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&executionTime, start, stop);
printf("SECTION 1 executionTime: %f", executionTime);
// SECTION 1

// SECTION 2
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);    // Reusing start event
cudaMemcpy(..., ..., ..., cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);     // Reusing stop event

cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&executionTime, start, stop);
printf("SECTION 2 executionTime: %f", executionTime);
// SECTION 2
```

Would this code give accurate estimates for execution time for section 1 and section 2 **since I'm trying to resue the cudaEvent_t start, stop for section 2 as well**? Or do I need to create two additional events start1 and stop1 for the second section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can re-use events.  The ability to do this is afforded by the fact that you can [record an event more than once](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html#group__CUDART__EVENT_1gf4fcb74343aa689f4159791967868446):

> If `cudaEventRecord()` has previously been called on event, then this call will overwrite any existing state in event. Any subsequent calls which examine the status of event will only examine the completion of this most recent call to `cudaEventRecord()`.

So this means that any timing measured using events will only pertain to the most recently recorded events.  In your case/example, that is basically self-evident, but in more complex cases, it should be noted that only the most recently recorded "version" of an event is "active".

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I had one more query. I have used cudeEventSynchronize(stop) after recording stop events in both sections 1 & 2. Is it necessary to do so for both the sections in this scenario or is it sufficient to call that function only in section 2?

Comment: In typical usage, it's necessary in both sections.  `cudaEventSynchronize()` is an *execution barrier* for the host thread.  It forces the thread to wait until the event in question has been encountered by the CUDA runtime (i.e. the GPU).  `cudaEventElapsedTime` will [return an error](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html#group__CUDART__EVENT_1g40159125411db92c835edb46a0989cd6) if one or both of the indicated events have not yet been encountered by the CUDA runtime.  Please refer to the documentation sections I have linked.